# Node.js I/O streams: piping output all the way back to web server

Tags: node.js, io, stream, pipe, output

## A little bit of background

Below you will find a diagram of the relationship between the different components of a Node app I'm currently working on.  [Here is the link on GitHub](https://github.com/boostup/plex-watch-later-videos-downloader).  It is an application that I use to archive videos which have strong journalistic importance, and between the moment I watch them, and the moment I get the time to use them for my reports, they are usually removed from youtube.  Hence, by archiving them, this information no longer gets lost.

[image]

## What I'm trying to achieve in plain English

`download_one_with_pytube.py` is basically a piece of code that downloads a video given an id, and so it reports its progress of the download by printing to the console the percentage of that progress.

## What I'm trying to achieve in terms of output piping

Here is a pseudo shell set of piped commands

`Array of IDs of videos | for each URL | python download(video Ids) | print progress | response.send(progress)`

The difficulty I have is to actually spawn the python code passing it the video id dynamically, and then pipe the progress all the way back to the server's response.

## Resources I've consulted & Stuff I tried

I've tried, the whole day yesterday, without success, implementing my own Classes of objects inheriting from EventEmitter, or even implementing my own deplex stream class to pipe that output all the back to my express web server so that progress can be served to the browser.

- [Advanced Node.js | Working with Streams : Implementing Readable and Writable Streams](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=nodejs-advanced&author=samer-buna&name=nodejs-advanced-m7&clip=2)
- [Util | Node.js v9.3.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)
- [How to create duplex streams with Node.js - a Nodejs programming tutorial for web developers | CodeWinds](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-31-nodejs-duplex-streams.html#what_is_a_duplex_stream_)
- [class Source extends Readable](http://decaffeinate-project.org/repl/#?evaluate=true&stage=full&code=Readable%20%3D%20require(%22stream%22).Readable%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Source%20extends%20Readable%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40content%2C%20options)%20-%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super%20options%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20_read%3A%20(size)%20-%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20%40content%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40push%20null%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40push(%40content.slice(0%2C%20size))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40content%20%3D%20%40content.slice(size)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0As%20%3D%20new%20Source(%22The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog.%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(chunk.toString())%20while%20chunk%20%3D%20s.read(10)%20%20%23%20print%20in%2010%20byte%20chunks%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%20The%20quick%20%0D%0A%23%20brown%20fox%20%0D%0A%23%20jumps%20over%0D%0A%23%20%20the%20lazy%20%0D%0A%23%20dog.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0As%20%3D%20new%20Source(%22How%20now%20brown%20cow%3F%22)%0D%0As.pipe(process.stdout))
- [Pipe a stream to a child process · Issue #4374 · nodejs/node-v0.x-archive](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4374)
- [Developers - Pipe a stream to a child process](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/81581-pipe-a-stream-to-a-child-process)
- [Deferred process.exit() to allow STDOUT pipe to flush by denebolar · Pull Request #1408 · jsdoc3/jsdoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/pull/1408)

## The problem

I think the problem is that i get confused with the direction the pipes should take.

## What I've managed so far

All i've managed to do is 'pipe' the outpout of the python script back to `downloadVideos.js`

## How the app is strutured

Through express (server.js in the diagram), I exposed my node app (running through a `forever` daemon) so that devices on the same LAN as the server can access [server IP address]:3333/startdownload and trigger the app execution.

## Looking at concrete lines of code in my repo

How can I pipe the output of [this console.log here](https://github.com/boostup/plex-watch-later-videos-downloader/blob/e46615e45f578387eaca85702b0360ea1723bcdb/downloadVideos.js#L19) all the way back to server at [this line of code here](https://github.com/boostup/plex-watch-later-videos-downloader/blob/e46615e45f578387eaca85702b0360ea1723bcdb/server.js#L11) ?

## A simple working example using Node's included http

I've got a [GIST here](https://gist.github.com/boostup/72e7130f0b56a51a9e0b14dde004215b#file-server-js-L30) of `http` server running that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.  However due to my app architecture being more real world than this simple example, I have several files and `require` statements in between the output I'm trying to pipe and the `res.send` statement.

## Conclusion

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide me on this.

[We could code together live using Cloud9 shared workspaces making this process easier.](https://docs.c9.io/docs/share-a-workspace)

[Here is the link to application.](https://ide.c9.io/boostup/plex-watch-later-videos-downloader), but I would have to send an invite for it to be accessible I guess.

Comment: How are things proceeding? I would propose to check out scramjet module if you're still stuck. I think I could help you to write the piping stuff in a couple lines.